# How to execute notepad once when the file is being moved using powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi I am new to powershell

Currently I am trying to write a script on powershell.

1. Monitor the Changes in a particular folder (C:\Users\CELINE\Desktop\Testing4)
2. If there is a new file detected, it will automatically move the file to another folder (C:\Users\CELINE\Desktop\PowerShellChanges2)
3. Automatically rename the moved file to "Request.csv"
4. Append incremental numbers to the file names when new files is being moved to the folder (eg. Request(1).csv, Request(2).csv, Request(3).csv etc)
5. Open a notepad after the file is moved

I am now stuck with point 5. 
I have no idea why when the file is being moved, multiple notepads are opened continuously but I only want to open one empty notepad

Anyone able to help?

Here are my codes

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher

#Path of folder to watch

$watcher.Path = "C:\Users\CELINE\Desktop\Testing4"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true 

#Action executed when changes detected

$action = { 


#SourcePath
$path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath

$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"

#Destination path
$dest = "C:\Users\CELINE\Desktop\PowerShellChanges2\Request.csv"

#Add Log file to monitor the changes 

Add-content "C:\Users\CELINE\Desktop\logtest5.txt" -value $logline

#Move Files

$actionMove = Move-Item -Path $path -Destination $dest

#Append number to filename

If (Test-Path $dest) {
    $i = 0
    While (Test-Path $dest) {
        $i += 1
        $renamefile "C:\Users\CELINE\Desktop\PowerShellChanges2\Request($i).csv"
        Rename-Item -Path $dest -NewName $renamefile
    }
}





#Execute Notepad


$FileExists = Test-Path $dest
If ($FileExists -eq $True) {C:\Windows\notepad.exe}
} 

#Event Trigger
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
while ($true) {Sleep 0}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if Notepad is already running, then launch a new instance if it isn't.  For example, change this part of your script:

```
$FileExists = Test-Path $dest
If ($FileExists -eq $True) {C:\Windows\notepad.exe}
}
```

To something like:

```
if ((Test-Path $dest) -and ((Get-Process | Where Id -eq $procId) -eq $null))
{
    $procId = (Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\notepad.exe" -PassThru).Id
}
```

This only checks for the specific instance of Notepad you launched previously from your script, but ignores any copies launched by other means.  You could easily change it to look for *any* instance of Notepad.

I had some issues with your code that stopped it working, even without this change, so I tweaked it slightly.  The code below should work properly:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher

# Path of folder to watch
$watcher.Path = "C:\Users\CELINE\Desktop\Testing4"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true 

$procId = -1
$i = 1

# Action executed when changes detected
$action = 
{ 
    # SourcePath
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath

    #Destination path
    $targetFile = "C:\Users\CELINE\Desktop\PowerShellChanges2\Request.csv"

    # Add Log file to monitor the changes
    Add-content -Path "C:\Users\CELINE\Desktop\logtest5.txt" `
                -value "$(Get-Date), $($Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType), $path"

    # Move file
    Move-Item -Path $path -Destination $targetFile

    # Rename file
    If (Test-Path $targetFile) 
    {
        $renamefile = "C:\Users\CELINE\Desktop\PowerShellChanges2\Request($i).csv"
        Rename-Item -Path $targetFile -NewName $renamefile
    }

    # Execute Notepad
    if ((Test-Path $renamefile) -and ((Get-Process | Where Id -eq $procId) -eq $null))
    {
        $procId = (Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\notepad.exe" -PassThru).Id
    }

    $i++
}


# Register event
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action | Out-Null

# Wait
while ($true)
{
    Sleep 0
}
```